# Swift presentViewController does not have the navigation bar

Tags: uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, swift

I am changing scene in my app using:

```
var view2:MainTableViewController = self.storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("view2") as MainTableViewController

self.presentViewController(view2, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

It's working but the problem is that in my first view i have a navigation bar but when i present the second view there is no navigationBar

Comment: it shouldnt have it. Embed your viewcontroller that is being presented with navigation controller.

Comment: open your storyboard. select viewcontroller. Then, Editor - Embed In - Navigation Controller

Comment: Ok thanks you can post it as a answer i will accept it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an Navigation Controller, if you need to handle different ViewControllers.

To add a Navigation Controller, you can simple use the Storyboard Editor.

Select the ViewController - Go to Editor - Embed in - Navigation Controller.

Or:

If you dont need an NavigationController, and just want to have a Navigation Bar, you can use a NavigationBar from the UIItems too. Just select it and drag it in Storyboard Editor to your ViewController. This could be useful when youre second View Controller is a Modal View (and you want to add Buttons to the Navigation Bar)

Comment: Even when I embed the presented view controller in a navigation controller, it doesn't give the desired effect.

Comment: try to set self.navigationController.navBarHidden = false

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work. I have it embeded in a navigation controller. The root view controller presents that view controller.

Comment: Maybe you set "Top Bar" in Storyboard to none?

Comment: No, I did not. But your second suggestion does work. Adding a separate navigation bar and not embedding a navigation controller. Thank you :D